# how to move text on mouse over in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make a link moving to left when mouse over? I want the text move back when mouse out. Is it possible with jquery? Please help.

Thank You

Comment: Did you know you can do this with `CSS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use CSS regardless if it's in jQuery or not, not sure why you would use jQuery to begin with, but anyways, here is an example:

```
 <a href="#">Move me Left</a>

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $("a").hover(function(){ $(this).css('margin-left','-50px') });
 </script>
```

The `margin-left` is set to -50px here (minus to go backwords), but can be changed according to your liking.

Otherwise in CSS all you would need to do is:

```
 a:hover { margin-left: -50px; }
```

See how much easier that is in CSS?